# TCP handshake ok, then the client isn't receiving any packets from the server

Tags: linux, ssl, tcp, linux-networking

Topology: Client ----- Intermediate Device ----- Server

Client: win7

Intermediate Device: unknown

Server: CentOS 5.8

The problem occurs when the client and server are trying to establish a SSL connection. It happens to one specific port, 2000. I haven't been able to replicate the problem with other port numbers.

I captured packets on both client and server. After the TCP handshake, from the client's perspective, it's not receiving ACKs for its previously sent packets so it kept re-sending them. On the server side, however, it did receive those packets and sent ACK packets.

The weird thing is, after the server sent those ACKs, it received a [RST, ACK] packet, from the intermediate device, for every packet it sent.

What could be the cause?

Comment: Are they on the same wire? (i.e: no other devices in between such as a firewall, router, ...)

Comment: @m1ke No they are not on the same wire. The server is located in an IDC, and the client is my own desktop using ADSL(or something similar)

Comment: Do you see any of the TLS handshake (Client Hello at least)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens after the SSL connection has been negotiated, it is possible that the intermediate device considers *encrypted* traffic on port 2000 as a potential security threat (or in some way "unwanted") and makes two things:

- intercepts the "ACK" sent by the server so they do not reach the client that will consider the server as not responding
- sends a reset to the server so that it will not keep the connection open waiting for traffic that will never come from the client

Comment: It happens during the SSL negotiaion; however, maybe the intermediate device thinks even trying to start an SSL session is a threat. Seems I have no choice but switch to another port.

Comment: You are correct: my statement has to be corrected into "If it happens after the *TCP* connection..."